# ASP Webforms JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm using VS 2015 and starting a new ASP C# Webforms project. The template includes ScriptManager. Issue is I can't get JQuery working on content page. Works fine of stand alone page. Please refer to my code.

Thanks,

Master page code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="PayrollTimeManagement.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>    

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
         <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>

    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />    

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, <asp:LoginName runat="server" />!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is code for my content page - code does not work. I but ref to jquery in both my masterpage and content page, does not work

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="PayrollTimeManagement.WebForm2" %>    

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">     

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/select2.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />       

     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () { $("#DropDownList1").select2(); });
</script>

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>aawe3wrw4t34t</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ss</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ff</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>rye</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>43t5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>rey</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Where is Your content page? Why you do not use ContentPlaceholder, and MasterPageFile?

Answer (score 0):

Add MasterPageFile Attribute:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm3.aspx.cs" Inherits="PayrollTimeManagement.WebForm3" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Site.master"  %>
```

And your content :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Please remove this code at your content:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

You should not input jquery js lib more than once.. 
You have put it on master page, so, do not need to put it again at content page.

Then to get component id you should use ClientId i.e.:

```
document.getElementById('<%=DropDownList1.ClientID%>').value
```

Maybe like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#<%=DropDownList1.ClientID %>").select2(); 
});
```

Comment: i pasted the wrong code, please review the code in my content page

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to declare the main jQuery files in master page alone. Content page which inherits the master page automatically gets those jquery files. It is not needed to declare in both the pages.